# Is Possible to Set a Widget Constraint Dynamically?

Tags: grails-2.0

I'm designing dynamic forms for grails and I was wondering if it was at possible to set the widget constraint dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the widget constraint is not the way to attack this. I suppose the simplest method would be to choose the tag you'd like to display based upon some condition using an "if" tag in your view or template. For instance:

Say you have a Book

```
class Book {

    String name

}
```

If you use Grails generate-view for this class, Grails will produce a template called _form that looks like the following:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: bookInstance, field: 'name', 'error')} ">
    <label for="name">
        <g:message code="book.name.label" default="Name" />

    </label>
    <g:textField name="name" value="${bookInstance?.name}"/>
</div>
```

You can test your condition in this form and change the view:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: bookInstance, field: 'name', 'error')} ">
        <label for="name">
            <g:message code="book.name.label" default="Name" />

        </label>

            <g:if test="$yourCondition">
                <g:textField name="name" value="${bookInstance?.name}"/>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <g:textArea name="name"  value="${bookInstance?.name}"/>
            </g:else>
    </div>
```

Now the view will display a textField or textArea field based upon $yourCondition.

Comment: The way I see it is that constraint widget sets the scaffold form input and I'd like to eliminate as much templating as possible. Either that or bind a "tag" or "template" to a entity.

Comment: It sounds to me like you will need to develop your own views in order to get the functionality you're looking for. Scaffolding in Grails isn't very useful for much beyond quickly testing out your app. The auto-generated views in Grails are the same as what you get with scaffolding, for what it's worth. You can get a lot accomplished by performing small modifications on those.